# Send custom variable in Email - contact form 7

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

|    add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'save_application_form'); 
    function save_application_form($wpcf7) {

```
        if ($wpcf7->id == 19) {

          $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['accessToken']);
            $service = new Google_DriveService($client);
            $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
            $file = new Google_DriveFile();

                  $wpcf7 = WPCF7_ContactForm :: get_current() ;
            $form_to_DB = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
            if ($form_to_DB) {

                /* @var $mail type */

                $uploaded_files = $form_to_DB->uploaded_files(); // this allows you access to the upload file in the temp location
                  $fileId = '';
            $cf7_file_field_name = 'file-181'; // [file uploadyourfile]
            //Do the magic the same as the refer link above
            $image_location = $uploaded_files[$cf7_file_field_name];
            $mime_type = finfo_file($finfo, $image_location);
            $file->setMimeType($mime_type);
            $test = pathinfo($image_location);

            $service->files->insert(
                    $file, array(
                'data' => file_get_contents($image_location),
                'mimeType' => $mime_type
                    )
            );
            $filetest = $service->files->get($fileId);
            $add = $filetest['items'];
            $final = $add[0]['alternateLink'];
            // the message
            $mail = "Link:" . $final;


       $mail = $wpcf7->prop('mail') ;

        $wpcf7->set_properties( array("mail" => $mail)) ;


                        // return current cf7 instance
                        return $wpcf7 ;
            }


        }

    }
```

|I have one function in that function I have one variable where I am storing share link. I want to pass this variable to contact form 7 mail

Comment: You want to send custom variable values into email ?

Comment: Do you get variable value?

Comment: Yes I want to send custom variable in mail

Comment: Yes I got variable value.

Comment: @P.patel issue solved ?

Comment: Issue not solved. Is there a solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check below code for your question.

```
            add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'my_add_custom_field' ); // its called befoee email sent
            function my_change_subject_mail($WPCF7_ContactForm)
            {
                $wpcf7 = WPCF7_ContactForm :: get_current() ;
                $submission = WPCF7_Submission :: get_instance() ;
                if ($submission)
                {
                    $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data() ;
                    // nothing's here... do nothing...
                    if ( empty ($posted_data))
                    return ;

                   $mail = $WPCF7_ContactForm->prop('mail') ;
                   // Your code
                   if ($WPCF7_ContactForm->id == 19) 
                   {
                        $filetest = $service->files->get($fileId);
                        $add = $filetest['items'];
                        $final = $add[0]['alternateLink'];
                        $mail . = "Link:" . $final;
                   }
                    // Save the email body
                    $WPCF7_ContactForm->set_properties( array("mail" => $mail)) ;

                    // return current cf7 instance
                    return $WPCF7_ContactForm ;
                }
            }
```

You only did one mistake that you are not saving the mail body.

Comment: $WPCF7_ContactForm->set_properties( array("mail" => $mail)) ;
return $WPCF7_ContactForm ;
I have to put just above two line right?

Comment: check my code properly if you put only that then you are not merging the original email so copy paste my whole function it will help you

Comment: mail sent but variable is not in the mail. Didn't find anything

Comment: If you check in my previous comment I had asked `Do you get variable value?` you said yes.

Comment: And edit your question from where you want to append your field?

Comment: I have changed code. I get share link when I do print_r($mail)
I want to just add $mail in mail

Comment: how array looks like when print_r ?

Comment: Link:https://drive.google.com/a/moontechnolabs.com/file/d/17xNxgz0Ch_rp0jc55D2-FJEw62BRU96G/view?usp=drivesdk

This is my print_r($mail); output

Comment: this link is asking for access

Comment: You are not loggedin so. I just want to send this link to mail